# Implementing a DSL with (subset) functionality of XSLT

Tags: xslt, antlr, dsl

My requirements are that I provide a way for Business Analyst-types to specify XSLT-like transformations without the complexity of XSLT or XPath.  Basically there are incoming XML documents and the client needs to be able to specify situations where elements/subtrees should be edited/removed/replaced/added.  It will essentially be a rules engine for applying XSL transformations.

My first approach was to come up with a DSL using an ANTLR grammar to parse into Java code  but I get the feeling I'm overlooking the KISS approach.  I've scoured the web but haven't been able to find any existing libraries/frameworks for providing a simple interface for applying transformations.  I feel like I'm missing the obvious solution but can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a reference to something that is said to address exactly your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Have you looked at [Altova MapForce](http://www.altova.com/download/mapforce/data_mapping_enterprise.html)**?